# Have some troubles with get fresh coordinates

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Here is my code. Actually, I want to use this service to get user's fresh coordinates. In my test it didn't work well. I didn't get a good location. And it seem never call mobile's GPS to update the coordinates. Is my code has bug or my phone has problem? Thanks

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
Boolean isWifiEnable;
Boolean isGPSEnable;
Context context;
Location location;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME = 1000 * 60;

public LocationService(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    bestLastKnownLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public Location bestLastKnownLocation() {

    location = null;
    String provider = null;
    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
      // location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
    isGPSEnable = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isWifiEnable = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates

    if (isGPSEnable == false && isWifiEnable == false) {
        // no network provider is enabled
        //showToastInAsync("No provider");
    } else {
        if (isWifiEnable) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
            Log.d("Network", "Network");
        }
        if (isGPSEnable) {
            if (lm == null) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
                provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

                Log.d("GPS", "GPS");
            }
        }

        if (lm != null) {
            location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
```

// At here  other PROVIDER doesn't work. Only passive work it is strange.

```
        }
    }

    return location;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

Comment: you need to do something inside `public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
`

Comment: also, you never request gps updates, because of `if (lm == null) {`

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, if (lm == null)  fixed. And in onLocationChanged what should I do ?

Comment: it is called when the location changes according to the criteria you gave. do whatever you have to do with the new location.

Comment: So, for example, if I moved then the onLocationChanged() would sniff the change automatical and I could update the coordinates. Is my understanding right?

Comment: that's what you ask when you call `requestLocationUpdates`, so yes. May be you should consider reading the doc?